# Cannot drop tablespace in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

HI,

problem 1

When i try to drop the tablespace using drop tablespace command, it fails and error message is the tablespace not exist.

when i do select * from dba_tablespaces, i can see the tablespace name.

Problem 2
when i try to connect the oracle using aquadata, i get "connection failed:- no more data to read from socket"

please suggest

Comment: Please ask *one* question per post.  The SO mechanisms are designed to focus on a single topic.  There is no charge for starting a new thread.

Comment: Please post the precise error messages, including the ORA numbers or whatever identifier you get.  The more information you provide the more likely you are to get a happy resolution.

Comment: Could be a uppercase/lowercase issue. If the tablespace name (in DBA_TABLESPACES) is in lower or mized case, you may need to quote it in order to drop it.

Comment: Sorry for adding two questions on same thread. @gary, when i execute query select * from dba_tablespaces, the tablespace name is shown in lower case. But i tried to drop it both the cases, but error thrown is database not found.. error code given is ORA-00959.. For problem 2 i will raise another thread

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "when i execute query select * from
>   dba_tablespaces, the tablespace name
>   is shown in lower case."

By default Oracle SQL is case insensitive.  That is, both of these statements are equivalent:

```
drop tablespace TS1 including contents
/

drop tablespace ts1 including contents
/
```

However, when it comes to storing metadata Oracle uses UPPER CASE for object names.  This doesn't matter unless when we created the database objects we wrapped their names in double-quotes.  At that point Oracle becomes case sensitive.

It appears such is your situation.  So you need to issue the command with the tablespace name in double quote:

```
drop tablespace "ts1" including contents
/
```

Comment: Yes, the database is created with "ts1" resulting in lower case